# HTMLAgilityPack iterate all text nodes only

Tags: html-agility-pack

Here is a HTML snippet and all I want is to get only the text nodes and iterate them. Pls let me know. Thanks.

```
<div>
   <div>
      Select your Age:
      <select>
          <option>0 to 10</option>
          <option>20 and above</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
       Help/Hints:
       <ul>
          <li>This is required field.
          <li>Make sure select the right age.
       </ul>
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**

1. Select your Age:
2. 0 to 10
3. 20 and above
4. Help/Hints:
5. This is required field.
6. Make sure select the right age.
7. Learn More

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(yourHtmlFile);

    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
    }
```

Will output this:

```
Select your Age:
0 to 10
20 and above
Help/Hints:
This is required field.
Make sure select the right age.
Learn More
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested @Simon Mourier's  answer on the Google home page and got lots of CSS and Javascript, so I added an extra filter to remove it:

```
    public string getBodyText(string html)
    {
        string str = "";

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        try
        {
            // Remove script & style nodes
            doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where( n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" ).ToList().ForEach(n => n.Remove());

            // Simon Mourier's Answer
            foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']"))
            {
                str += node.InnerText.Trim() + " ";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Trying to implement your code, i got an "BC30491: Expression does not produce a value" error on n.Remove()