# Read text from webpage, not HTML

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to make an app that downloads all the mp3s from a webpage, but i'm not downloading them from the source. I'm downloading from http://ytcracker.com/music/ and for each song listed, if you copy and paste it to the end of the url, it comes up with the link for that song. I'm using a WebClient to download the files, and if i could readline on the webpage not the html, then i can just do `client.DownloadFile(url + line, path)`  Here's my code:

```
var url = "http://ytcracker.com/music/";
var sr = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("http://www.ytcracker.com/music/" + line);
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.ytcracker.com/music/" + line, @"C:\Users\Lavi\Downloads\downloadto\.mp3");
    }
}
```

the problem is 'line' gets the source of the page, not the text. if there's any way to get the text of the page, please help me out. thanks!

EDIT: also, where the path is, i know it says '.mp3' instead of a file name and then .mp3. i'm going to create a for loop and add to a list each time it loops until the page is all read, and then add them to the .mp3. so it will be like 'i.mp3' and so the mp3s will be in a folder like 1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, etc.

Comment: You don't need to prefix your title with "C#".  
Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 2):

The simplest means I know to get the text out of the HTML source (which is all you will be able to get without parsing the HTML) is [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

There are straightforward tutorials on the site in addition to the software.

See the question below for guidance on pulling out the text specifically with HTML Agility Pack

[HTMLAgilityPack iterate all text nodes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344771/htmlagilitypack-iterate-all-text-nodes-only)

Answer (score 2):

In your case to download music, you will need to read the href values and make sure they are .mp3 files before constructing the path. As Eric J mentioned HtmlAgilityPack is easier to use.
Just download and add the dll reference to your project and then use this code.

```
        var url = "http://ytcracker.com/music/";
        var sr = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sr.ReadToEnd());
        foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
            if (att.Value.EndsWith(".mp3"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("http://www.ytcracker.com/music/" + att.Value);
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.ytcracker.com/music/" + att.Value, @"C:\Users\Lavi\Downloads\downloadto\.mp3");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression. Try this out, it's your code - I just add regex:

```
var url = "http://ytcracker.com/music/";
var sr = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string line;

var re = new Regex(@"<li><a href=.*mp3.>(.*)</a></li>");

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        if (re.IsMatch(line))
        {
            var match = re.Match(line);

            client.DownloadFile("http://www.ytcracker.com/music/" + match.Groups[1], @"C:\Users\Lavi\Downloads\downloadto\.mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, regular expressions are not always the best solution :-)  What if the page he's scraping changes substantially?  It's much easier to adapt the code using a full-fledged HTML parser than by changing regular expressions.

Comment: Agree. Regex is a solution a solution, not the best one.